# JavaFx: How to close window by calling afterburnerFx view?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to close the window by calling its view.

```
DashboardView dashboardView = new DashboardView();
      Stage stage = (Stage) dashboardView.getScene().getWindow();
      stage.close();
```

When I run that code, I get NullPointerException... Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Show us the `stacktrace`. I think you must add `dashboardView` to your `Scene`

Comment: It just said NullPointerException.